# How to sort list by another list?

Tags: excel, sorting

I have excel list of names(Datalist) and I need to sort it to be in exact same order as similar list(Patternlist).

How can i sort Datalist to have same order as Patternlist?

Patternlist(each letter is first cell in a row):

```
X
Y
Z
Q
```

Datalist(each letter is first cell in a row):

```
Q 
X
Y
Z
```

Comment: Will you always have the same number of items in both lists? You may want to read up on how to provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and come back to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54080798/edit) to provide a better example. a `VLOOKUP` may do the job, but it's hard to tell at the moment

Comment: VLookup wont do it. I need to sort this exact list (i added colored backgrounds). Every list have exact same number of items.

Comment: Excel has a custom sort.  It allows you to set the sequence.  How to use that would be a better question on SuperUser.

Comment: Found answer here:
https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3867-excel-sort-rows-to-match-another-column.html#a1

Comment: Alternatively you can add a new column to your Patternlist. Add numbering to that column 1-whatever and then use vlookup to bring over that column, upon which you can sort.

Answer (score 0):

Manually doing it :

1. Label each row in Patternlist with 1,2,3,..
2. use index match to generate a 'sequence' list from the Datalist

`=index([Datalist_QXYZ],match([1st_named_cell],[Patternlist_XYZQ],0))`

3. copy the generated sequence list and paste as values, then sort.

(3b) If you need to actively generate new list.. then use rank() to manually sort it.

Hope it helps..

Comment: Manually it would be too much (original list got over 700 items). I used "Match" to find position of item in Patternlist and then i just sorted using those positions.
https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3867-excel-sort-rows-to-match-another-column.html